# Why »werden es« and not »wird es« in this sentence from »Der Spiegel«?

Tags: grammatical-number

The four below sentences appear in today's article “[Von Dürre betroffener Landwirt. "Beschissen wäre geprahlt"](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/trockenheit-wie-ein-landwirt-mit-der-duerre-kaempft-a-1220485.html)” from *Der Spiegel*:

> Nachdenklich schaut Stegen [a German farmer] über sein Feld. Die Sonne brennt vom Himmel. Es ist noch früh am Tag und trotzdem schon 30 Grad heiß. Bis zu 36 Grad werden es an diesem Julitag werden.

Why *Bis zu 36 Grad **werden** es* in the last sentence above and not *Bis zu 36 Grad **wird** es*? I don't know how to explain it, but *werden es* in this particular case does not read well to me.

Answer (score 14):

"Bis zu 36 Grad werden es" is correct as "36 Grad" is plural.

The Duden gives the examples "es waren 35 Grad [Celsius] im Schatten" and "draußen herrschten 25 Grad Wärme, Kälte".[Grad, der (2.)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Grad#Bedeutung2)

If you add "warm" it has to be "Bis zu 36 Grad warm **wird** es" as "warm" is now the *Prädikativum* and *36 Grad* is an attribute of "warm".

Comment: @EugeneStr. - but, of course, singular for one degree: in dieser Nacht war es 1 Grad.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is sloppy at the best, as can be seen at the similar:

> Bis zu 10 Minuten dauert es....

where the plural would more clearly seem wrong. The given sentence would also be more clean, if it would read:

> Bis zu 36 Grad **warm** wird es...

since it is then a simple measurement scale specification. The other argument for the singular is that *es* is the subject. But as it stands, it is somewhat gray area and the plural is only justified by being more than one *Grad*.

Summarized: feel free to use the singular instead (I consider it as better), adding *warm* gives bonus points.

Update:

The situation allows different approaches, each of which has supporters, see this canoo.net post

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Nomen/Numerus/Menge.html) also explains

> Männliche und sächliche Maß-, Mengen- und Münzbezeichnungen werden im Nominativ Singular gebraucht, wenn sie hinter einer Zahlenangabe stehen...

So in contrast to some other answers: *Grad* is masculine, and so the singular is perfectly legal.

Comment: Cannot downvote, but this is plain wrong!

Comment: @FredBob: Comments which claim to have found errors without specifying them are useless.

Comment: As stated in RHa's answer, the Duden gives examples of the same form. Therefore I see no reason to call them sloppy. *"Bis zu 36 Grad wird es werden."* is wrong. Your update from Canoo.net is about *Grad* itself and means that you don't say *"36 Grade"*, but *"36 Grad"*.

Comment: Du kannst die Verben "dauern" und "werden" nicht auf diese Weise miteinander vergleichen, da sie syntaktisch anders verbunden werden. Ein sinnvolles Beispiel, das den Plural bei "36 Grad werden es" erklärt ist dieses: "Aus diesen Samen werden 36 Blumen." => "Es werden 36 Blumen." => "36 Blumen werden es."

Comment: guidot, niemand behauptet, dass der Singular falsch sei. Aber **das Verb im Beispielsatz ist im Plural**, also ist auch sein Bezugswort im Plural, also ist "Grad" im Beispiel **nicht Singular** sondern Plural. Der Beispielsatz ist nicht "sloppy", wie du behauptest, sondern korrektes Deutsch.

Answer (score 2):

> Why "Bis zu 36 Grad **werden** es" in the last sentence above and not "Bis zu 36 Grad **wird** es"?

That's because the werden refers to the "Grad". "Grad" is the same word, in singular and in plural and it is the subject of the sentence, which the verb relates to.

If you use

> Bis zu 36 Grad heiß wird es an diesem Julitag werden.

then the wird refers to the "es" and is in singular.

But you might also get away with "Bis zu 36 Grad wird es an diesem Julitag werden.", because it can refer to an implied "heiß" or the "Temperatur" as a noun.

If you change the order to

> An diesem Julitag **wird** es bis zu 36 Grad werden.

it gets more cleary wrong, while

> An diesem Julitag **wird** es bis zu 36 Grad **heiß** werden.

sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

"36 Grad" is plural.

Note how in English ("36 degrees") and Russian ("36 градусов") you also use plural.

"Grad" commonly has no plural ending. There is "Grade", but that is uncommon in this phrase.

---

To better understand the phrase "36 Grad werden es", think of an example with a noun with a plural form that is more clearly different from the singular, such as "Blumen" (Flowers):

```
Diese Samen werden 36 Blumen.        (These seeds will turn into 36 flowers.)
Es (= diese Samen) werden 36 Blumen. (replace "diese Samen" with "es")
36 Blumen werden es.                 (rearrange the sentence)
```

You will note how "Blumen" is plural. Just as "Grad" is plural.

---

Of course it is correct to use the singular as well:

> 36 Grad wird es an diesem Julitag werden.

Here, both the verb ("werden") and the noun ("Grad") are in the singular, although the number is not distinct from the plural in the latter.

Comment: This is somewhat debatable see update of my answer.