# 'In Berlin sind es 30 Grad.' or 'In Berlin ist es 30 Grad.'

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-usage

Google translates "In Berlin it is 30 degrees." as "In Berlin **sind** es 30 Grad." Is 'sind' correct here?

If so, why is the plural used? And why, if the adverb 'in Berlin' is omitted or moved to the another position does the verb is then singular: "Es ist 30 Grad", "Es ist in Berlin 30 Grad"?

Comment: Another option would be _"In Berlin **hat** es 30 Grad."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ as far as I know, this is rather a regional usage

Comment: @closevoter why do you consider this question off-topic? The OP does not simply ask for a translation or proofreading, he asks "why", in other words the rule for that - therefore it is absolutely within the scope of this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why »werden es« and not »wird es« in this sentence from »Der Spiegel«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46185/why-werden-es-and-not-wird-es-in-this-sentence-from-der-spiegel)

Comment: @Arsak maybe regional in Germany, but pretty much standard in Austria (using a form of _sein_ here sounds unnatural to my ears, unless from a German).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is as usual: it depends.

On a first look you would say, it has to be

> Es sind 30 Grad

in contrast to

> Es ist 1 Grad.

The difference can be easily spotted: 30 is expressing a plural, 1 is singular. The same is true for other constructions like this:

> Wie weit noch? Es sind noch 30km bis nach Berlin! *How far? It's still 30km to Berlin*
>   Wie weit noch? Es ist noch 1km bis nach Berlin!

**However**:
You could take a different approach:

> Heute ist es warm.

I'm not really familiar with grammatical terms, but you can now add a descriptor to warm

> Heute ist es [sehr | ziemlich | gar nicht | 30 Grad] warm.

**Speculative answer**: It doesn't work with the first three descriptors, but you can (at least colloquially) leave the warm implied:

> Heute ist es 30 Grad [warm]

Comment: Und was ist mit *draußen sind es null Grad*?

Comment: Das scheint sich analog zu unbestimmten Zahlwörtern zu verhalten. Dort sind keine / null Kinder.

Comment: I agree with the first part, I'm not so sure about the second. It's true that _Heute ist_ (not: _sind_) _es 30 Grad warm_ is correct (the NP _30 Grad_ is an example of the "adverbial accusative" just discussed in another thread, it doesn't determine the _ist/sind_ question). Where you lose me is the last suggestion, i.e. that "warm" can just be omitted. Do you have any source for that or is that merely speculative? It's not impossible but the assumption that speakers just drop the _warm_ is of course quite bold. (By the way, to me, _Heute ist es 30 Grad_ sounds incorrect.)

Comment: That's really not my point. It's one thing to claim "People say _Heute ist es 30 Grad_ colloquially" (which I doubt, intuitively, but maybe you're right), it's another thing to claim "They say it because they omit the word _warm_". One is an observation, the other is an explanation for that observation. However, the explanation does not logically follow from the observation; they may say it - provided they actually do - for an entirely different reason. That's why I asked if you have a source for that claim.

Comment: I second that speculation ;-)