# Was ist die richtige Rolle von "statt" in Sätzen?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, grammar-identification, genitive

Ich weiß, dass *statt* in drei Formen eingesetzt werden kann: Genitiv, Konjunktion und Dativ:

Langenscheidt:

1. stạtt: Konjunktion ≈ anstatt: Sie drehte die Heizung auf, statt sich wärmer anzuziehen; Statt dass wir hier herumsitzen, sollten wir lieber spazieren gehen
2. stạtt: Präp; mit Gen/gespr. auch Dat ≈ anstatt: Nimm doch das frische Brot statt des alten

Ich weiß auch, dass es im Genitiv zwischen zwei Nomenia *der/des* gibt. Aber in folgenden Sätzen bin ich verwirrt:

1. warum gibt es **den** nach dem **statt**? Falls es Genitiv ist, wäre es unmöglich, dass **den** nach Genitiv kommen kann. Und in der Konjunktion tritt **statt** wie *statt dass* auf.

> Satz 1: “Auf plötzliche und unerwartete Weise kamen die Vereinten Nationen zu dem Schluss, dass ***statt den*** erwarteten Temperaturanstieg um 3,5 Grad, die Temperatur wahrscheinlich um 5,8 steigen wird.” **Quelle**: Schriftlicher Ausdruck alle Themen von [Dr Deutsch](https://t.me/s/d_deutsch?before=105)

2. Warum gibt es **der** nach **statt**? Falls es Genitiv ist, müsste es **des** sein, weil Grad maskulin ist.

> Satz 2: “Das Klimagremium der Vereinten Nationen erwartet bis zum Jahr 2010 einen Temperaturanstieg um schlimmstenfalls 5,8 Grad Celsius ***statt der*** bisher erwarteten 3,5 Grad.” **Quelle**: Fit Für den Testdaf, Hueber Verlag, Seite 101.

Comment: Spekulation: Das *Temperaturanstieg um* wurde nachträglich eingefügt ohne daran zu denken, dass es dann *des Temperaturanstiegs* lauten muss.

Comment: Ja genau,  Ich dachte auch das. Falls es Genitiv ist, wäre es (des Temperaturanstieges), weil Genitiv Form von Anstieg (Anstieg[e]s) ist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das erste Beispiel ist schlicht falsch. Im zweiten ist es tatsächlich ein Genitiv, "3,5 Grad" ist Plural.

Comment: Plural von (Grad) ist (Grade). Quelle: Duden

Comment: Im Gegensatz zum Englischen (degrees, kilometres, pounds, euros) sind Einheiten im Deutschen im Singular.

Comment: @Toobatf, ich hatte letzte Nacht keine Lust, dafür Verweise zu suchen. Ich habe jetzt nur Fragen auf Englisch gefunden: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/54900/3237 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/46185/3237

Comment: Das ist sehr hilfreich. Danke

Answer (score 2):

Naja, im ersten Beispiel war wohl "statt dem Temperaturanstieg" oder "statt den Temperaturanstiegen" gemeint, was eben jeder umgangssprachliche Dativ ist, der dem Genitiv den Garaus macht. Beispiel 2 ist wie bereits erwähnt Plural. Du sagst ja etwa "33 Grad **ist** 1 Grad mehr als 32 Grad" aber "34 Grad **sind** 2 Grad mehr als 32 Grad". Grad ist in diesem Fall eine physikalische Einheit (Grad Celsius), und Einheiten werden nicht dekliniert.

Aber eine Grundregel in Zahlangaben ist, dass alles, was nicht mit "1" quantifiziert ist, als Plural aufzufassen ist — selbst dann, wenn es weniger als eines ist. Also 0.7 ... wäre Plural, 2/5 ... wäre Plural, 1/5 könnte auch als Singular gebraucht werden.